# What is the name of this mechanism

Tags: mechanical-engineering

[image]

can someone tell me please the name of it or any info about it

Comment: Where is the legend?

Comment: Who says it's a "mechanism" ?  My initial reaction is that's a retaining screw used only for transport, and the hook is intended to hang free when in use.